# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'description' cannot be null (SQL: insert into) in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

i'm trying to add a new comment into my 'posts' column on my database, however I am getting this error [QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'description' cannot be null.

although I filled the description fields in the form!!!

```
ajax:
    $('#frcoments').on('submit',function (e) {

         e.preventDefault();
            var description = $('#description').val();
            var da = new Date();
            var dat = da.toLocaleDateString();                
            var ti = new Date();
            var tim = ti.toLocaleTimeString();
            var dat_tim = dat.concat(" ",tim);  
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {description: description},
                success: function( data ) {

                info.hide().find('ul').empty();

                if(!data.errors){
                $("#respod").append('<div class="fils-body"><p style="margin-bottom:3px; font-size:12px">'+data['description']+'</p></div>');
                document.getElementById("description").value="";
                $("#description").focus();
              }else{
                  $.each(data.errors, function(index, error) {
                    info.find('ul').append('<li>'+error+'</li>');
                });
                  info.slideDown();
                $("#description").focus();
              }
            },
            error:function(){}
            });
    //  }
     });   

view:
            {!! Form::open(array('url'=> $jour->users_id.'/journal', 'method'=>'POST', 'id'=>'frcoments')) !!}          
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">      
            <div class="form-group">
              {!! Form::text('description', null, ['class' =>'form-control', 'style'=>'border-radius: 0']) !!}
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Publier', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger')) !!}    
            </div>  
            {!! Form::close() !!}

controller:
  if($request->ajax()){
      $coment=Input::get('description');
      $Coments= new \App\Post;
      $Coments->journals_id = '5';
      $Coments->date = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
      $Coments->aimer='0';
      $Coments->naimer='0';
      $Coments->description=$coment;
      $Coments->save();
    return \Response::json($Coments);
  }else{
        return 'no';
    }
```

Comment: Aren't you setting your `description` to `null` in the ajax like so `document.getElementById("description").value="";`?

Comment: yes I empty immediately after saving in the database.

Comment: And how exactly are you able to save to the database from a javascript code? Isn't that a job of the controller?

Comment: even if I remove the line of document.getElementById("description").value=""; the error persists !?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a null value in the "name" field, but you haven't defined this column as nullable.
Try to use the `->nullable()` method in the "name" definition in your migration. Take a look in this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns

Comment: I do not have a name field!?

Comment: how I should do to make nullable the name field in the migration?

Comment: Take a look in your database, because the error is descriptive: "Column 'name' cannot be null". If you have this field in your table, modify it and put it as nullable.

Comment: I do not have a name field in the database!
sorry I made a mistake in the title, I mean the field 'description'.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jesus Amierio mentioned

> You are trying to insert a null value in the "name" field, but you
>   haven't defined this column as nullable. Try to use the ->nullable()
>   method in the "name" definition in your migration.

But if you don't want to dirty your hands on migrations just go to the table where `description` column lives and insert a related value there it would work.

Comment: how I should do to make nullable the name field in the migration?

Comment: Go to your Laravel project >> Database Directory >> Migrations >> Find the migration where description field is preset. Append `->nullable()` to description it will look like `description->nullable();` Then run `php artisan migrate:refresh` from command line.

Comment: when I do php artisan migrate:refresh I get this message : [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'db_metie
rs.posts' (SQL: drop table `posts`)

Comment: the error is gone when I use description-> nullable(); but in this case I can not fill the description column!!!

Comment: Insert a related value to description field . What do you mean you can't fill ? Can you insert a value in there from PHPmyadmin

Comment: I can view the values inserted into the description field.
I meant the description field is required, I can not put null.

Comment: Yes you are right. There should be a value, this is why you are getting error. I mentioned that you should insert a value there and that value should be related to your table.

Comment: In your case there should be `$coment;` value in `$Coments->description` field.

Comment: I know that the $coment variable must have a value, but why $ Coments-> description does not receive a value !?

Comment: try var_dump or dd($comment) and tell me what it prints.

Comment: where I try var_dump or dd($comment), in controller?

Comment: I have nothing with var_dump!

Comment: in below the response when i use var_dump($coment);                        <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre>{"journals_id":"5","date":{"date":"2016-08-13 20:05:14","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"aimer":"0","naimer":"0","description":null,"updated_at":"2016-08-13 20:05:15","created_at":"2016-08-13 20:05:15","id":8}

Comment: now var_dump($Coments->description). Tell me is there any data inserted in database in description field ?

Comment: <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><font color='#3465a4'>null</font>
</pre>{"journals_id":"5","date":{"date":"2016-08-14 09:15:19","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"aimer":"0","naimer":"88","description":null,"updated_at":"2016-08-14 09:15:21","created_at":"2016-08-14 09:15:21","id":15}

Comment: Yes the database is updated.
but when I try to insert the data without using ajax, the description field is filled perfectly!!!

Comment: Happy to know it works so the problem was with your ajax . Accept the answer.